# Python using same date/time in multiple files

Tags: python, datetime

I'm currently generating three different xml files, and I would like to have the second and third file have the same date/time as the first file.
In the first file, I do

```
import datetime
time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

This gives me the format I would like. I've tried multiple approaches such as storing it in a different variable and importing it to the second and third files, but it seems that it'll always keep the actual current time and not the time of the first file. I don't know if there's a solution to my problem using the datetime module but if anyone has any ideas that would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you call that function, whether directly or through import it will always run again and give a new "now".

If the same program just uses that string for 3 times there shouldn't be a problem, but if you're running 3 different scripts you will get 3 different dates!

To avoid this, I would save the first generated string to a file:

```
with open('.tmpdate') as f:
    f.write(time)
```

And read it in the next to files:

```
with open('.tmpdate') as f:
    time = f.read()
```

And finally, just to clean up after yourself, you can delete that file after it was used for the 3rd time with `os.remove('.tmpdate')` (you need to `import os` before that, of course)

Comment: Why are you doing this? How will this result in the 3 files having the same created timestamp?

Comment: It's not what he wants, he wants 3 different scripts to use the same string as a timestamp for something else, not as a file property (modified or created), re-read the question, that's what I understand of it

Comment: @Keller Han feel free to correct either of us if we're off or mistaken in understanding you

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the first time. He mentioned xml files and then pasted python code which threw me off.

Comment: Thank you Ofer, your solution meets my needs. Sorry for the confusion Shiva, what I meant was that I have three xml templates, and I'm using python to fill out the templates. One of the attributes that all three share is a time ID, and I need that time ID to be consistent throughout the three files.